# Calculations with PS Output fields using PS Client

Tags: peoplesoft

I am working with Peoplesoft Client 8.53 And need some assistance on working with output fields.

**Problem statement:** I have a union Query. Both the selections (Query 1, Query 2) are fetchng some count. Now, i want to do some calculation with Count from Selection1 and Count from Selection2.

Below is the screenshot of sample data with 2 selections showing one output field(**Term**) from selection1, similarly there is another Count from selection2.

[image]

Kindly help me understand if there is any way to do calculations with output fields, as we have in Oracle.

Your support would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the text of your ideal SQL query?

Also, note that UNION will consolidate any counts that are identical in result into a single row.

```
SELECT 8 AS COUNT FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 8 FROM DUAL
```

My first thought is that you might be better of with a JOIN. The join would allow you to add the two sums.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view:

NEW VIEW:

```
Select COUNT from Selection1
union
Select COUNT from selection 2
```

On the Query Manager:

```
Select sum(count) from NEW_VIEW
```

In other words, you use the SUM function to do that.